# Applications Remains or not when Update windows to 8.1 from 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update

I want to know if I install windows 8.1 on a windows 8 computer. Then is it uninstall all the applications that I installed on windows 8?

Comment: I think this question belongs more to this site : http://superuser.com

Comment: I don't think so, because It is possible to ask windows related questions in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Windows 8.1 on a Windows 8 computer, previously installed applications will remain. If there are any applications detected that won't work with Windows 8.1, you will be prompted with a list of these prior to update (for example, if you use the Checkpoint VPN client)